# Advanced routing

Tags: url, routes, slug

I am trying to do this. Have a structure url like so: /{id}-{slug} and /{parent.id}/{id}-{slug}

I need the slug on the url but I only for SEO, I want craft to ignore the slug and only go for the ID. So even though it is /{id}-{slug} for craft it would be /{id} and so on.

What would be the recommended approach? Advanced routing? Manually remove the -{slug} and search by {id} on the template? Any other way?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably setup the following routes:

```
'blog/*/*' => 'blog/entry',
'blog/*' => 'blog/entry',
```

And then on the entry template I'd get the last segment and [split it](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html) to get the ID like so:

```
{% set segment = craft.request.lastSegment | split('-') %}
{% set id = segment[0] %}
{% set entry = craft.entries.id(id).first %}
```

That should work for either of your {id}-{slug} examples. Though in practice I'd probably fetch the entry using the slug and not the ID as I think it looks prettier and I don't like IDs in URLs.

Comment: Thanks Clive! I will give it a try! The id in the url is a requirement for this particular project.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been trying to figure this out myself and have a slightly different approach that might work the same with a little less code.

```
'blog/*/id-<entrySlug:{slug}>' => 'blog/entry',
'blog/id-<entrySlug:{slug}>' => 'blog/entry',
```

The 'slug' variable with it's value from the url will be available in the template without having to do anything else.